# How to do that fomvalidation io will always looking for validating a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, formvalidation.io

im validating a form with form validation io, what happends if that im cloning de entire form before submiting via ajax, if i got a error in the back, a load a error msg with a button where if clicked load the form again, but the validator not loger working once is loaded.

Here is a part of my code, if someone could help me:

```
        $.on("success.form.fv", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form= $(e.target);
                var modal= $form.children(".modal-body");
                var datos= $form.serialize();
                var modalClonado= modal.children(".row").clone();


                $.ajax({
                    success: function(data) {
                        if ("user" in data) {
                            modal.html(error+data.user+cerrarError);
                        } 
                    }
                });
                $form.on("click", "button", function(){
                    modal.html(modalClonado);   
                    $form.find("#submit")
                            .removeClass("disabled")
                            .prop("disabled", false);
                }); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing your original form from the DOM and then replacing it with a new one you will not have a validator attached to it. You would have to add another validation object to your form that will validate your form when you try and submit the new one.

Why do you need to completely replace your original form if it does not pass validation? Would it be easier to instead allow the user to edit any invalid fields on the original and allow them to resubmit the form?

edit:

Once you get your results from your validation you can use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the submission of the form when the validation does not pass and also append your error message wherever necessary. This will leave your form as is (no navigating away from the page or needing to refresh the page) and the user can go back into the form to edit any fields that are invalid and then attempt to resubmit the form where the same validation process will take place again.  If the form does successfully validate you can submit your form using `.submit()` on your form. `$('#formToSubmit').submit()`. This way you just need to add your validator object to your original form once, and then the user can keep attempting to submit the form until it is successful.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do, how you may do that?

Comment: the formvalidation plugin that im using already has a submit event ( thats  the code above), with clone() and html() and already inserting the form as was before submitiing, my problem is that once it get done, its no loger validate the form